# Ошибка в Visual Studio "unresolved import 'PyAudio'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, pip

Я начинающий программист на Python 3.7.8, но возникла проблема.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, VS просто не видит пакеты и вопрос, а что делать то?

Comment: Если их нет, то видеть он их соответственно не будет

Comment: Может ты вправо посмотришь? Я спрашивал про PyAudio

Comment: Тогда стоит уточнить вопрос

Comment: Тебе ни чего не говорит в названии **Ошибка в Visual Studio “unresolved import 'PyAudio'”**?

Comment: @Миша Вверху в списке переключи интерпретатор с pyqtt на обычный python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кароче, хоть и мозолит глаза, но проще не обращать внимания, так как всё работает